# Parse managed file

Tags: 7, forms, files

I am very new to Drupal 7 module development and I have been working to develop a module where it parses a file after the user uploads it. I am using hook_forms, but for some reason I can't get a submit handler to be called after I click upload, or attach a submit handler.

```
$form['r_file'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => t('R file'),
    '#upload_validators' => array('file_validate_extensions' => array('xlsx')),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://babies',
    '#default_value' => variable_get('r_file'),
    '#description' => t('For all the babies in the world'),
    '#progress_message' => t('Uploading file...'),
    '#progress_indicator' => 'bar',
    '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

Where can I attach a handler so that when the user clicks upload/remove, I can conduct some post processing?

What I meant is according to this section, https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file
it says "The form's validate and submit handlers receive a file object ID in $form_state['values'] that represents the ID of the new file in the {file_managed} table."

Then it goes on describing what should go inside the submit handler. My question is, how should the submit handler look like?

Hope that clarifies the question.

Comment: You may need to provide more of the code context, it's hard to see the entire problem there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that you are looking for this hook_file_insert (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_insert/7)
It is being called once managed file is inserted to database which is exactly what it occurs when you hit the upload button of file upload widget.

Comment: This method to get the file does work, but for my purposes, I ended up using hook_form_alter. I realized that because I did not clear the cache, the function wasn't being called.